# Update mysql with C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, mysql, post, mysqli

hi i have mysql db and php file called upd.php i want update my database record with c# and php i used bellow code[Method 1] everythings is ok and work fine

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Crypted";
$password = "appCrypted";
$dbname = "Crypted";

// Post Method
//$hwInfo = $_POST["hwInfo"];  
$trial = $_GET["trial"];  
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET trial='$trial' WHERE hwInfo='4871-1598-0155-1531'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

C# Code:

```
string urlAddress = "http://localhost.ir/ClassSRM/upd.php";
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
                    {
                      { "trial", "10" }
                };
                Console.WriteLine(urlAddress);
                Console.WriteLine(postData);

                string pagesource = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(urlAddress, postData));
            }
```

now if i enter this link http://localhost.ir/ClassSRM/upd.php?trial=3000 my record update successfully, but i want send hwInfo from c# to upd.php, i used bellow Code [Method 2] but nothing work

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Crypted";
$password = "appCrypted";
$dbname = "Crypted";

// Post Method
 //$hwInfo = $_POST["hwInfo"];  
$trial = $_GET["trial"];  
$hwInfo = $_GET["hwInfo"];
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET trial='$trial' WHERE hwInfo='$hwInfo'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

C# Code:

```
string urlAddress = "http://localhost.ir/ClassSRM/upd.php";
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
                    {
                      { "hwInfo", hwInfo },
                      { "trial", "10" }
                };
                Console.WriteLine(urlAddress);
                Console.WriteLine(postData);

                string pagesource = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(urlAddress, postData));
            }
```

Comment: var_dump($_GET); and check the response

Comment: which statement i must edit? i am newer in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is old question but it may help somebody. Your example works but I made some change in PHP code, I use POST method, here my working example:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Crypted";
$password = "appCrypted";
$dbname = "Crypted";

$trial = isset($_POST['trial']) ? $_POST['trial'] : '';  
$hwInfo = isset($_POST['hwInfo']) ? $_POST['hwInfo'] : '';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET trial='$trial' WHERE hwInfo='$hwInfo'";
echo "sql: " . $sql;
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```